# Java Date after before time not working as expected in production

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
long treatmentTimeBeginDay;
if ( effectiveBegin.after(businessClosing) ) {
    LOGGER.debug("Compute treatment time for beginDay = 0: the effective begin {} is after business closing {}",
                            config.formatLogDate(effectiveBegin),config.formatLogDate(businessClosing));
    treatmentTimeBeginDay = 0;
} else {
    LOGGER.debug("Compute treatment time for beginDay between {} and {}",config.formatLogDate(effectiveBegin),config.formatLogDate(businessClosing));
    treatmentTimeBeginDay = businessClosing.getTime() - effectiveBegin.getTime();
}
Preconditions.checkState( treatmentTimeBeginDay >= 0 , "Internal bug! treatmentTimeBeginDay="+treatmentTimeBeginDay );
```

effectiveBegin and businessClosing are not null, also checked by Guava preconditions and you can see it in the logs...

It runs fine in most cases but in production we have these errors:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal bug!
>   treatmentTimeBeginDay=-852

I don't give you the rest of the stack/code because it should be enough...
The exception is explicitly raised by my Guava checkState call.

I also have the log:

> DEBUG [BusinessHoursUtils.java:257] llairie - Compute treatment time
>   for beginDay between 7/19/12 8:00 PM and 7/19/12 8:00 PM

(I can't have log with millies for now)

---

What i'm trying to understand is.

If i get the log i gave you, this means that the test `if ( effectiveBegin.after(businessClosing) )` is false, so effectiveBegin should be before or equals to the businessClosing.

In this case effectiveBegin timestamp should be lower than the businessClosing timestamp.

So when i do `businessClosing.getTime() - effectiveBegin.getTime();` i would expect to have a positive number.

So please can someone tell me why i have -852 milliseconds in my exception message? How is this possible?

---

**Edit:** I was suspecting a tricky case where the after/before method wouldn't work for milliseconds and it seems that's the problem since i could reproduce it locally.

The 2 dates at runtime are:

```
businessClosing = {java.util.Date@503}"Thu Jul 19 20:00:00 CEST 2012"
fastTime = 1342720800000
cdate = null

effectiveBegin = {java.sql.Timestamp@498}"2012-07-19 20:00:00.999"
nanos = 999000000
fastTime = 1342720800000
cdate = {sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date@512}"2012-07-19T20:00:00.000+0200"
```

With these runtime objects, `effectiveBegin.after(businessClosing) = false`
If i set in DB effectiveBegin = 2012-07-19 20:00:01.000, 1 millisecond later, then the test = true

In both cases i would expect to have `effectiveBegin.after(businessClosing) = true`

It seems, like ametren suspected, that my dates are different.

So in the end, what's the problem? 
Aren't we supposed to be able to compare the 2 date instance with a millisecond precision? 
Even if they are subclasses of the java.util.Date?

Comment: What is the type of effectiveBegin?

Comment: Didn't some other piece of code modify the `Date`? This class should be deprecated, ran through a shredder and burned.

Comment: deleted irrelevant guava and scjp tags. even though you are using a guava method, your question is not about guava

Comment: ametren it's a java.sql.Date! Good point!

Comment: i've edited my question with some extra info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you mix Timestamp and Date. `Timestamp.after(Date)` compares only the milliseconds of the Date components, which are both `1342720800000` in your example.
However, `Timestamp.getTime()` does also consider the Nanoseconds (`999000000ns = 999ms`) that are stored within the Timestamp and will return `1342720800999`. So `businessClosing.getTime() - effectiveBegin.getTime()` will return `-999` as result.

To solve this issue, you could modify the if-statement to `if(effectiveBegin.compareTo(businessClosing) > 0)` or you could convert the `businessClosingDate` to a `Timestamp` before the if-statement.

Comment: If Timestamp compares only the milliseconds, why can't it find that effectiveBegin is after businessClosing since it has 999 more milliseconds?

Comment: Because when you call `Timestamp.after(Date)`, you effectively call the `Date.after(Date)` method, which considers only the milliseconds.

Comment: Added possible solutions to the answer